# Learn python the hard way, exercise 35

Tags: python

I'm having some problems with exercise 35 in "Learn python the hard way".

```
def bear_room():
    print "There is a bear here."
    print "The bear has a bunch of honey."
    print "The fat bear is in front of another door."
    print "How are you going to move the bear?"
    bear_moved = False

    while True:
        next = raw_input("> ")

        if next == "take honey":
            dead("The bear looks at you then slaps your face off.")
        elif next == "taunt bear" and not bear_moved:
            print "The bear has moved from the door. You can go through it now."
            bear_moved = True
        elif next == "taunt bear" and bear_moved:
            dead("The bear gets pissed off and chews your leg off.")
        elif next == "open door" and bear_moved:
            gold_room()
        else:
            print "I got no idea what that means."
```

a) I don't understand why the While activates. In line 6 we write that the bear_moved condition is False. So if it's False, and While activates when it's True, it shouldn't activate!

b) I also have problems with the AND operator in the IF and ELIF lines. Why are we asking if bear_moved changes in value?? No other instruction in the block affects bear_moved other than line 33 (but that line exits the while).

I'm not sure I've explaned myself, please do tell me if I haven't. And thank you for your answers, i'm a complete newbie.

http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex35.html

Answer (score 2):

a) The `while` loop does not test `bear_moved`it tests `True` which is, well, always true.

b) The difference is, you may only move the bear once - a second time would be fatal. This serves to distinguish. But I don't consider it good style - a better way would be

```
    elif next == "taunt bear":
        if bear_moved:
            dead("The bear gets pissed off and chews your leg off.")
        else:
            print "The bear has moved from the door. You can go through it now."
            bear_moved = True
```

Answer (score 1):

`while` loop executes its body while the boolean condition is true. `TRUE` is always true so it is an infinite loop.

Answer (score 1):

a) It says `While True` not `While bear_moved`, `True` is a constant, so this while loop will go on forever.

b) Since the while loop goes on forever and some answers ("taunt bear") can change the value of `bear_moved`

Executing this function will keep asking questions until you either die or `gold_room()` is executed.

**Edit**: With die I do mean the `dead()` function is executed, and not that you yourself would die, I honestly hope you remain in good health while learning Python :-)

Answer (score 1):

**a) I don't understand why the While activates. In line 6 we write that the bear_moved condition is  False. So if it's False, and While activates when it's True, it shouldn't activate!**

This `While True` construct **creates an infinite loop**. This will loop until a `break` statement or some other control flow changing statement occurs.

**b) I also have problems with the AND operator in the IF and ELIF lines. Why are we asking if bear_moved changes in value?? No other instruction in the block affects bear_moved other than line 33 (but that line exits the while).**

The code you provided appears to model the following situation: The user is stuck in a room, with a bear. They need to input the correct actions to make the bear move away from the door, and then they need to exit the door.

The **infinite while loop maintains that if the input the user gives does not change the control (functions `dead(...` or `gold_room()`) then the program will wait for input again**.

Initially, the bear has not moved, so `bear_moved` is false. When the user inputs `taunt bear`, this will make the bear move away from the door, making `bear_moved` true. At this point, if the user attempts to `taunt bear` AGAIN, then the bear will kill them. However, if the user inputs `open door` after they have taunted the bear *once*, they will move to the next room.

Answer (score 0):

> a) I don't understand why the While activates. In line 6 we write that the bear_moved condition is False. So if it's False, and While activates when it's True, it shouldn't activate!

while True just means loop indefinitely until a break.

Each time the while loop starts, it checks if True is True (and it very obviously is) so it loops forever (again, or until a break).

bear_moved is a variable that has nothing to do with the execution of the while loop.